# Best practice siging with rsa certificate

Tags: c#, rsa, x509certificate, sign

I have a web service which need the body signing on all the requests. so i wonder what is the best practice in order to do that? I'm using this method in order to sign the string but i guess its not the best way. because my private key never disposes:

```
using (var provider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
{
    provider.ImportParameters(ProjectValues.PrivateKey.ExportParameters(true));
    encryptByteList = provider.SignData(content, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"));
}
```

I already read the certificate and private key once when the project loaded for first time. Like this:

```
Certificate = new X509Certificate2("my pfx path", "***", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
PrivateKey = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)Certificate.PrivateKey;
```

Then I found this method:

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2("my pfx path", "***", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
using (var rsa = cert.GetRSAPrivateKey())
{
    encryptByteList = rsa.SignData(content, HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
}
```

but this one works if i read certificate from file on every requests. obviously its not a efficient way

Comment: You can't have your cake and your pie too.   You do not want to get the private key on every request, but you do not want to keep the key either.  These are completely opposite requirements and you can't have both at the same time.

Comment: thanks dear @jdweng. i don't have a problem with keeping the private key. but its exposable and as far as i know i shouldn't have keep this kind of objects. if my first method is safe i keep it. but deep down i know there should be a better way.

Comment: The best practice is to rely as much as possible on the security of SSL/TLS, and only do something custom if you have unique requirements, e.g. non-repudiation.

Comment: thanks dear @PresidentJamesK.Polk. but its not my choice. the service provider force us to use this new security methods .